# Dashcode web clip icon, I have tried everything and it won't show up

Tags: html, favicon, dashcode, apple-touch-icon

I can't get my dashcode web clip icon to show up, it just shows the safari generated icon.  I have tried using dashcode to design it, then I used the code

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="Images/WebClipIcon.png">
```

I also tried adding a file named apple-touch-icon.png to the root folder and that still didn't work.  I have run the site on the simulator, my iphone, and my ipad and the custom web clip icon will not show up.  Does anyone have a suggestion

Update:  I just created a new dashcode project and tried adding a webclip icon and it still won't work.  This is really starting to frustrate me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the image to the image file that is outside the mobile photo

Answer (score 0):

I will add 1 thing that caused this issue for me.  After trying all of the documented fixes, I tried adding a background color to my icon.  Originally, I had a transparent background.  Once I added a background color to the .png file, it all just worked.

My steps:
Use GIMP to create a 72x72 image with 7 layers and a transparent background layer.
Save a copy as apple-touch-icon.png and add to my web app's root folder.
Launch the website on my iPad 2 running IOS 5.0.1.
"Add to Home Screen"
RESULT: A black icon on the home screen.
Back in GIMP, fill the background with a color.
Overwrite my .png file.
Back to iPad safari to reload the site.
"Add to Home Screen"
The icon shows up now as documented.

My conclusion: sufficient or well placed transparent areas in the icon image will prevent iOS from accepting it as valid and cause it to be rejected.